# How to frame this query in gremlin

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using the Amazon Neptune graph database.  I have a SQL query  in Java.

```
select start_dt from maint_actv where rec_id = "+ Id + " and start_dt is not null limit 1
```

Q) How to express the "start_dt is not null" in Gremlin ?

Answer (score 0):

A property value cannot be null when using Amazon Neptune. The property either exists on a vertex or edge, or it does not. You just need to test for that existence.

```java
g.V().has(‘start_dt’)
```